# Bash conditional based on whether a file has changed since last pull

Tags: bash, mercurial

I'm writing a script for automatically updating a system of ours. Basically I want to do a pull and update from a remote hg repository, and then run some update scripts. Now the problem is that these update scripts takes a while to run and most of them only has to be run if there has been changes to their configurations.

Now my script looks like following:

```
if hg pull -u
  then
    run scripts
fi
```

What I want is something like

```
if hg pull -u && 'some changes was introduces in my/configuration/directory/*'
   then
      run scripts
fi
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With templated output of `hg incoming` your can check before pull, which files will be modified on pull (if any will be) and will act accordingly

`hg incoming --template "{files % '{file}\n'}" | grep SOMESTRING`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hg status` to get a list of files that have been changed between revisions, for example files modified between `tip` and it's parent(`tip^`) that are in `my\configuration\directory`:

```
hg status my\configuration\directory\** -m  --rev "tip^:tip"
```

I would recommend to `pull`, check if those files have been altered from the current revset, `update`, and then run your scripts if your config has changed. To me that looks easier than trying to store which revset you started with and figure it out after the update.  (Note that I'm not great with bash/grep, so this is approximate and untested):

```
hg pull
cfgChngd = hg status -m my\config\dir\** -m  --rev tip | grep "M my\config\"
hg update
if cfgChngd
    runAllTheScripts
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the status command to get a list of changed files -- also between different revisions:

```
HERE=`hg log --template '{node}' -r.`
hg pull -u
if hg st --rev $HERE:. | grep -q .
then
  run scripts
fi
```